Is it possible to make an inherited function call a derived overloaded function?
Suppose I have 3 classes:
example.h
class Object {
public:
    Object();

    void pass_self_to_external_class();
};

class ObjectWithExtraMember : public Object {
public:
    ObjectWithExtraMember();

    int extra_member;
};

class ExternalClass {
public:
    ExternalClass();
    
    void do_something_with_object(Object* object);
    void do_something_with_object(ObjectWithExtraMember* object);

    int extra_member_val;
};

example.cpp
#include "example.h"

ExternalClass e;

Object::Object() {}

void Object::pass_self_to_external_class() {
    e.do_something_with_object(this);
}

ObjectWithExtraMember::ObjectWithExtraMember() {
    extra_member = 45;
}

ExternalClass::ExternalClass() {
    extra_member_val = 0;
}

void ExternalClass::do_something_with_object(Object* object) {
    extra_member_val = 0;
}

void ExternalClass::do_something_with_object(ObjectWithExtraMember* object) {
    extra_member_val = object->extra_member;
}

If an instance of ObjectWithExtraMember calls pass_self_to_external_class(), is there a way to make it so pass_self_to_external_class() calls ExternalClass::do_something_with_object(ObjectWithExtraMember* object) instead of ExternalClass::do_something_with_object(Object* object)?
The solution I'm currently using in my actual project is to create a function ObjectWithExtraMember::pass_self_to_external_class() which has the exact same behavior as the Object version.
Is it possible to force the inherited version to pass the instance of the derived class without doing that?

@DanielA.White You can use "deducing this": template<typename Derived> void pass_self_to_external_class(this Derived& derived) { e.do_something_with_object(&derived); }

Concepts to research: double dispatch, visitor pattern. The ideal solution would be to just move the functionality to the Object hierarchy, but I assume you cannot do that for some reason.

Having a function like your pass_self_to_external_class() is common and normal in these solution, but you can eliminate the repetition with CRTP.

@RaymondChen Deducing this is nice but such functions cannot be made virtual, which is often (not always) needed in code like that.

I think we can use CRTP to handle this.
class ExternalClass;

template<typename T>
class Object {
public:

    Object() {}

    void pass_self_to_external_class(ExternalClass &e);

    T* get_instance() {
        return static_cast<T*>(this);
    }
};

class ObjectWithExtraMember : public Object<ObjectWithExtraMember> {
public:
    
    ObjectWithExtraMember() {
        extra_member = 45;
    }

    int extra_member;
};

class ExternalClass {
public:
    ExternalClass() {
        extra_member_val = 0;
    }

    template<class T>    
    void do_something_with_object(Object<T>* object) {
extra_member_val = object->get_instance()->extra_member;
}
    // void do_something_with_object(ObjectWithExtraMember* object);

    int extra_member_val;
};

template<typename T>
void Object<T>::pass_self_to_external_class(ExternalClass &e) {
    if constexpr (std::is_void<T>::value == false) {
        e.do_something_with_object(get_instance());
    } else {
        e.extra_member_val = 0;
    }
}

Test code.
int main(int, char**)
{
    ExternalClass e;
    

    ObjectWithExtraMember derived;
    
    derived.pass_self_to_external_class(e);
    cout << e.extra_member_val << endl;

    cout << e.extra_member_val << endl;
    return 0;
}


In your code Object<void> and ObjectWithExtraMember are unrelated classes and not parts of a class hierarchy.

You can simplify the design by having pass_self_to_external_class unwrap to the instance before calling do_something_with_object: void pass_self_to_external_class(ExternalClass& e) { e.do_something_with_object(static_cast<T*>(this)); }. Now ExternalClass doesn't need to know about the CRTP type. (@n.m.couldbeanAI can be fixed by having Object<T> derive from a common ObjectBase.)

"can be fixed by having Object derive from a common ObjectBase" This is not what the original design has. ObjectWithExtraMember derives from Object, not from any of its parents. It is important that do_something_with_object can be made virtual.
